# Cannot find Run a Child Flow in MS Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, powerapp, power-automate, microsoft-flow

Based on [Call Child Flows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform-release-plan/2019wave2/power-automate/call-child-flows), there must be an action called "Run a Child Flow" in MS flow, but I cannot find it, Does anyone know why?Does it need a CDS license?

Is there any other way to call a flow and wait for its response in MS flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like the article you provide, you need to follow the steps then you can have a the "Run a Child Flow". First You need to navigate to the **solution** on your left hand. first create a new `solution`(Or goes to an existing one). Then create the child Flow first. After that, create the Parent Flow in the solution, then you will find the `Run a child flow` action. And you can find the child flow you created before.

[image]

You possibly have done it through clicking on `My flows` rather than doing it in the `Solution` tab, (and it seems it does not need CDS license??).

"For example, you may have multiple flows that are part of a project you are working on. While working on, or managing these flows, you don’t want to have to scroll and search for these flows when you want to access them.

Solutions address deployment needs by allowing you to export and import a set of flows (and apps). In addition, you can organize these flows within a single ‘container’ which simplifies navigating and managing these flows."

I suggest reading the rest of [this](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/solutions-in-microsoft-flow/) Microsoft Walkthroughs.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was missing the solution part, I was doing it in the "My flows" rather than the Solution, much appreciated.

Comment: I have added a few sentences to make your answer more comprehensive. Please review and advise, it has also a question too, if not sure please delete it.

Comment: Appreciate if you could have a look at this one too https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/283703/run-a-child-flow-and-request-to-xrm-api-failed-with-error-message-flow-client