# Run a child flow and Request to XRM API failed with error: 'Message: Flow client error returned with status code "BadRequest" and details

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, flow, powerapp

I am getting

```
 Request to XRM API failed with error: 'Message: Flow client error returned with status code "BadRequest"
```

and unable to figure out the issue. For debugging I have done the below steps:

1- I am able to run a child flow with several variables as the input and several variables as the output (i.e. without any connection).

2- As soon as I add `Get Items` to the child flow (of course after fixing the connection string) I am not able to save the parent flow and the ugly below error will appear.

```
        Request to XRM API failed with error: 'Message: Flow client error returned with status code 
    "BadRequest" and details "{"error":{"code":"ChildFlowsUnsupportedForNonOpenApiConnections","message":"The workflow with id '9e0dde55-numbers----00d3a6aa1e4', name Child_IdenitifyChanges_ApporvalEmailV1
    cannot be used as a child workflow because it is on an old version of Flow. 
    Please re-create it inside a solution."}}". Code: 0x80060467 InnerError: Type: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, 
    Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=numbers]] Message: Flow client error returned with status code "BadRequest" and details "{"error":{"code":"ChildFlowsUnsupportedForNonOpenApiConnections",
    "message":"The workflow with id '9e0dde55-numbers-000d3a6aa1e4', name Child_IdenitifyChanges_ApporvalEmailV1 cannot be used as a child workflow because it is on an old version of Flow. Please re-create it inside a solution."}}".
    StackTrace: at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.
    Update(Entity entity, InvocationContext invocationContext, CallerOriginToken 
    callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType, Boolean checkAdminMode, Boolean 
    checkForOptimisticConcurrency, Dictionary`2 optionalParameters) at 
    Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataExecutionContext.Update(Entity entity, UpdateOption updateOption) at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataServiceDataProvider.
```

some screenshots

Parent:
[image]

Child:
[image]

Child Connetion String:
[image]

and the content of `Get Items` of child by clicking on `Peek Code`

```
 {
"inputs": {
    "host": {
        "connection": {
            "name": "@json(decodeBase64(triggerOutputs().headers['X-MS-APIM-Tokens']))['$connections']['shared_sharepointonline']['connectionId']"
        }
    },
    "method": "get",
    "path": "/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('https://orgnameeee.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName'))}/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('298cb3af-sime digits-2e672809fb2d'))}/items",
    "authentication": {
        "type": "Raw",
        "value": "@json(decodeBase64(triggerOutputs().headers['X-MS-APIM-Tokens']))['$ConnectionKey']"
    }
},
"metadata": {
    "flowSystemMetadata": {
        "swaggerOperationId": "GetItems"
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are all the flows inside a solution? What happens if you recreate the flow inside the solution, as suggested in the error message? Have you done anything that is recommended in the error message?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Both are in the same solution, I created the child flow from an empty template rather than exporting, but I copy-pasted the actions (just variables) but created Get Items from scratch (step 2) .

Comment: Have started creating my long child flow from scratch without copy-pasting- So far so good, will report the outcome here. I have noticed that if there is a typo or an issue in the child, I will receive the same ugly erroe, so this error may indicate some typos rather than some issue with the version of the flow.